# Install required application before installing my application

Tags: android, installation

It is my challenge to install an application (like the `MediaPlayer` that i programmed before) and after that, install and run my new application that depends on last installed application. Could any one please give me an idea to do like this ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your title and your question are different, but Did you check out this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that MediaPlayer should be automatically installed when the user wants to install your new app, but that it should install MediaPlayer first, that's just not going to work. You don't have any control over the install process, especially not before your app is even installed.

What you can do, though, is have your new app start with an activity that simply checks for the existence of the required app, and if it doesn't exist, prompt the user to install it. If the app exists, move on to the rest of the app.